# Can I store my Perl artifacts in Artifactory?

Tags: perl, cpan, artifactory

Is anyone out there using Artifactory with Perl?  I'm wondering if it can proxy CPAN, and interact with the `cpan` command-line tool.  Any links to documentation, or stories (success or otherwise) would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Currently Artifactory doesn't have a dedicated `cpan` support. We'll appreciate [a feature request](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/).

Saying that, if cpan doesn't require a special APIs or indexing calculation there is no reason you can't just use Artifactory with `cpan`. You can proxy any http repository with [a custom layout](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Repository+Layouts) and it should just work.

Comment: `cpan` does indeed require a special index.  Here's an example of such an index: http://www.cpan.org/modules/02packages.details.txt

Comment: Thanks. Please vote and watch - https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-6203

Answer (score 1):

You might also consider [Pinto](http://metacpan.org/pod/Pinto) or [Stratopan](https://stratopan.com).  These are not as sophisticated as Artifactory, but they are designed specifically for managing Perl build artifacts and will integrate seamlessly with the Perl toolchain.

*Disclosure: I operate Stratopan.*

Comment: Can we use artifactory to proxy to a custom stratopan?